# Is there a way to speed up max of a column in pyspark?

Tags: python, pyspark

I have big dataset with 20 columns and I need to find max and min values of each one. Other transformations which are not primitive hadn't taken more than 3-5 minutes on whole dataset. But to find just a max value of one column(!) it spends 10-12 minutes. Currently I tried this approach:

```
df.agg({"x": "max"}).collect()[0]
```

and this approach:

```
df.select(F.max(F.col("x")).alias("max")).limit(1).collect()[0].max
```

They both spend approximately the same time of 10-12 minutes. Is there a way to find a problem or to speed up this process? I have a intuition that finding max value should not be such an expensive operation. Or should I try finding max value of all columns simultaneously?

Comment: what kind of output are you looking for? a scalar value? how do you intend to show max and min values for all columns? i would do `max_dict = df.select(*[F.max(i).alias(i) for i in df.columns]).collect()[0].asDict()`

Comment: How are you running it? Is it using the Jupyter notebook? If yes, jupyter notebooks in general are not given too much resources, generally a single executor only to work with. So, if you have a large dataset it may take some time.